# How old is Captain America when he receives the 'Super-Soldier Serum'?

Tags: marvel, captain-america, age

[Steve Rogers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America) is said to have been born in the 1920's.  WWII started roughly in 1939 with the invasion of Poland by Germany.  Rogers attempts to enlist in the US Army in 1940, however due to his frail physical state he is denied entry.

Having been observed by certain key Army officials attempting to enlist several more times after being denied, he is inducted in to Project Rebirth as its first candidate for Dr. Erskin's Super-Soldier Serum.  After receiving said serum, and becoming the pinnacle of human potential he operates in the European theater of war for several years alongside Bucky Barnes and, on occasion members of the Invaders.

On his final mission during the war he and Barnes are presumed dead when the experimental bomb they are attempting to stop from destroying Washington DC explodes dumping Cap in the Arctic waters to be frozen and preserved for many years before he is found and revived by the founding members of the Avengers.

I'm trying to figure out how old he was when he received his serum treatments and became Captain America, and/or how old he was when he was frozen in the ice.

Comment: Anyone care to elaborate on the downvote?

Comment: Didn't downvote, but might have been due to the unnecessary synopsis before the actual question.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to Captain America's biography on [ComicVine](http://marvel.wikia.com/Captain_America_%28Steven_Rogers%29#cite_note-.27.27.27.5B.5BCaptain_America_Vol_1_283.7C.27.27Captain_America_.27.27_.23283.5D.5D.27.27.27._In_contradiction_with_the_fact_that_Rogers_was_supposed_to_have_a_.5B.5BSteven_Rogers_.28Revolutionary_War.29_.28Earth-616.29.7CRevolutionary_War_era_ancestor.5D.5D_already_living_in_the_colonies_that_would_become_the_U.S.A._versus_both_of_his_own_parents_were_immigrants_themselves_from_outside_the_U.S.A._If_true.2C_the_Revolutionary_War-era_Rogers_or_his_direct_descendant_who_maintained_the_surname_of_Rogers_left_the_USA_after_its_initial_formation_as_an_independent_country.-0); The comic version of Steve Rogers was born on [July 4th, 1920](http://marvel.wikia.com/Captain_America_Vol_1_283). He was given the Super-Serum in March 1941 (aged 20).

This is flatly contradicted by the [film version](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Steve_Rogers) which states that he was born on July 4th, **1918** and turned into a superhero aged 21.

Both versions agree that was frozen in 1945 (aged 25 and 27 respectively).

Comment: ...really *July 4th*?!?  That's a little much.

Comment: @Monty129 - Geddit?! He was born on July 4th, just like America!! I bet Stan Lee slapped his knee when he thought of that one.

Comment: I was going to correct you by pointing out that Joe Simon and Jack Kirby *originally* created Cap, but the cornyness of that date leads me to believe that only mr "Excelsior!" himself could have come up with that part.

Comment: @Monty129 This was in an era where he regularly punched Hitler in the face.  And you think him being born on July 4th is the odd contrivance?

Comment: @Zibbobz over 200 times if I remember correctly.

Comment: For what it's worth (not much probably) this change was probably made so that Steve's father could die from "Mustard gas."  If he had been born in 1920, he would've been conceived in 1919, after the war was over.

Comment: @Dave - I assumed it was because 30 year old Chris Evans couldn't conceivably play a 20 year old. Making him 22 makes it a smidge more believable.

Comment: Given what they accomplished with his 90 lb weakling body, I doubt removing a few lines/adding some baby fat to his face was a big concern.

Comment: Thomas Jefferson and John Adams both died on July 4, 1826.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the above answer, but in the movie version Steve was 26 because he went into the ice before his birthday - March 5th.

[image: Newspaper headline saying "ROGERS DISAPPEARS", from "The Nation's News Source", dated NEW YORK, MONDAY MARCH 5, 1945.]

I know the number for the day in the picture is hard to read, but it seemed like either a 3 or a 5 to me and **the only Monday in March 1945 with a 3 or a 5 in it is the 5th**.

Answer (score -2):

Okay so, technically Steve Rogers a.k.a. Captain America was born in 1918 in the films but 1920 in the comics, so based on the current year and time, C.A. is actually 99 years old with the body of a 25 year old and in the comics is 97 with the body of a 27 year old.